Why won't my HTML script tag read from my JS file in Next.js
I am just starting with Next.js I have been trying to access the web cam for a project I have been working on but I have found an issue when it comes to writing in the "script" tag
Here is the simple code for page.js
export default function Live(){
return(
    <html>
        <body>
            <video id="webCam" autoPlay width="600" height="600"></video>
            <a download>Take Picture</a>
            <script src="myscript.js" />
        </body>
    </html>
);
}

Here is the code for the "myscript.js" file
console.log("in")
const webCamEle = document.getElementByID("webCam");
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true}).then((stream)=> {
    webCamEle.srcObject = stream
}).catch((error) => {console.error(error)});

I don't even get the console logs which leads me to believe that it's not finding the file at all. Every video I have followed showed that I have been doing the right things and when I run the app, all I get is the button popping up. I'm hoping to get a live camera feed to pop up eventually but now I just want to know that the "myscript.js" file is being read.

Check the network tab of the developer tools of the browser and see if there are requests for myscript.js. It may not be finding it if the file is not in the same place as the HTML file.

Why is there a script tag in your nextjs code?  It must be imported like any other component or js file.

Does this answer your question?

You need to use component structure, create a component MyWebcam.js:
"use client";

import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const MyWebcam = () => {
    const videoRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUserMedia = async () => {
      try {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true });
        if (videoRef.current) {
          videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    getUserMedia();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <video ref={videoRef} autoPlay width="600" height="600"></video>
      <a download>Take Picture</a>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyWebcam;

page.js
import MyWebcam from "@/components/MyWebcam";
export default function Live(){
return(
    <html>
        <body>
            <MyWebcam />
        </body>
    </html>
);
}


Thank you for the help, this has worked perfectly! Just out of curiosity, do you mind explaining why a component structure is needed? I'm just interested to know if it is a Next.js thing or a better practice, etc.
